# Anisotropic Shader and Denoising

Tags: cycles-render-engine, denoise

So, I have a scene where I had 8-16 samples set and Denoising checked, which worked great for smooth metals in the scene.

Now I added one piece of anisotropic metal and was confused why the anisotropy is looking weird.

Then I realized the denoising was washing out the anisotropy, so when I turned off the denoising the metal looks properly rough-sanded.

Unfortunately that meant that the transparent glas I also have in my scene now has many small specs in it and looks weird.

How can I have anisotropic metal and smooth glas surfaces in the same scene?

PS: Here's without denoising, 256 samples. The anodized metal looks great but the glass looks very noisy:

[image]

Compare to a render with denoising on, the glas looks better but now of course the metal surface isn't sparkly anymore:

[image]

Comment: Hello :). 8-16 samples is *very* low for Cycles. Denoising works best with 500+. Without sufficient samples, it distorts finer details.

Comment: Please update your question with some images to demonstrate the issue. This will help people to suggest solutions in the same context as your problem.

Comment: Yes of course, I ran it with 256 samples with denoising on/off for comparison.

Comment: You can separately render metal and glass parts and denoise only last one.

Comment: @SergeL do you have a Link or a reference to documentation about that in Blender? I've never done anything like that.

Comment: Some general info on multilayer rendering: https://artisticrender.com/how-view-layers-can-help-you-render-large-scenes-with-less-memory-in-blender/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I managed to setup a system with two layers, and now the smooth objects behind the glass look smooth. Thing is, the are where the glas just has background and no objects behind still looks blurry: https://i.imgur.com/Ue2HF4W.png